# Logical index of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

In Maltab logical indexing can be done as follows. Given two binary image masks `A` and `B`:

```
C = A(B)
```

Given two numpy array `A` and `B` of bool type, any simple way to do the same operation in Python?

Comment: logical as A[True,False,...False,True] ?

Comment: Yes, `numpy` supports this directly.  `C = A[B]` gives you all elements of `A` where `B` is true.  `numpy` was, in general, designed to be a Matlab replacement for Python.

Comment: if B is a logical array `B.dtype == 'bool'` then `A[B]` if B has other type then `A[B==1]`

Comment: Applying a mask *to another mask* with logical indexing would be a pretty unusual operation. Are you sure `A` and `B` are both supposed to be masks?

Comment: Mask operations can be used for finding common or uncommon pixels

Answer (score 1):

Let's supose that we have an array and want to find the values greater then 50.

Code:

```py
import numpy as np

array = np.array([80, 35, 50, 70])

greater_then_50 = array[array > 50]

print(greater_then_50)

# output:
array([80, 70])
```

That is an exemple boolean indexing in numpy.

Every time you make a boolean operation with a numpy array, it returns a boolean array that has True and False and when we pass this boolean array as a mask to another array, it will returns only the positions that has True in the boolean array.